# How to judge whether a process is running in the foreground(Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, shell, jobs

Recently I've been trying to implement a job control shell in c and I got the above question.

When I type a command it gets executed in the foreground, at the same time I could not do anything to the terminal until it finish, in other words, it controls the terminal.

Back to the question, the gnu documents give a showcase in which it tests whether stdin_fileno is a tty. Here are my questions:

1. Does this mean that when a process is running in the foreground it is also controlling the terminal? If not what's the difference?
2. Stdin fileno is a micro anyway. Why would it differ between process?

Comment: *"there could be a group of process running in the foreground"*. Can you give an example? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I don't know if the same is true in Linux, but in Windows each process can open a separate terminal/console window.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying controlling the terminal?

Comment: @Charles Duffy that was my point. The console is tied to that process.

Comment: @Aval sorry I forgot to mention I'm actually implementing a job control shell. when I type a command and press enter, the command control the terminal

Comment: @AvalSarri sorry, I didn't get the reply right, please take a look at the comment above

Comment: If you implement a shell **yourself** that allows multiple foreground jobs to run in parallel, then you are the only one that can answer your question *"in this case which process exactly controls the terminal?"*.

Comment: @Socowi I see, seems there is only one process controlling the terminal then. What about  part one of the question?

Comment: @Hans Please [edit] your question to add all information there instead of using comments for this purpose. You should add more information about what you want to achieve. There is a term "controlling terminal" which means that the teminal controls the process not the other way round. Your shell should store all required information about the processes. You still did not explain what you mean with "a process is controlling the terminal". More than one process can send data to the terminal or change its settings.

Comment: Also define what you mean with `run in the foreground / background`.

Comment: These terms are all defined in the [Posix standard Base Definitions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03). Also lots of useful info in the description of the [General Terminal Interface](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11).

Comment: Removing the bash flag, as the OP is trying to implement their own shell, rather than work with any preexisting one (much less work with bash specifically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Recently I've been trying to implement a Job control shell in c and I
> got the above question The gnu documents give a showcase in which it
> tests whether stdin_fileno is a tty.

I suppose you mean [the section of the Glibc manual describing the implementation of a job-control shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html).  If not, then that's definitely something you *should* be reading.

> Here is my question: does this
> means that when a process is running in the foreground it is also
> controlling the terminal?

No. Although terminals do each have one controlling process, that has little to do with foreground and background.  We are usually more interested in the controlling terminal of a process -- that is, a terminal that in some sense controls the process, not the other way around.  Foreground and background are related to this latter concept.

Processes belonging to the foreground process group of a terminal can read from that terminal and write to it.  Other processes cannot successfully do so -- they will block or be suspended if they try.

> If not what's the difference? I realize
> there could be a group of process running in the foreground as a job,
> so in this case which process exactly controls the terminal?

All of the processes in the foreground process group of a given terminal can read from the terminal and write to it.  They do not need to be the terminal's controlling process to do so, and often they are not.  But they do normally have the terminal as their controlling terminal.

**With regard to the question update:**

> When I type a command it gets executed in the foreground, at the same
> time I could not do anything to the terminal until it finish, in other
> words, it controls the terminal.

Describing that as the process controlling the terminal is fraught, especially from the perspective of implementing a shell, because it is a manifestation of foreground *vs*. background, not of the terminal's "controlling process".  Processes in the foreground process group do not (generally) *control* the terminal, but rather have special *access* to it.  Part of the job of a job-control shell is to mediate that access.

Comment: "**3.114 Controlling Process** The session leader that established the connection to the controlling terminal. If the terminal subsequently ceases to be a controlling terminal for this session, the session leader ceases to be the controlling process." (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_114). The controlling process is the process which will receive SIGHUP when the terminal is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks, @rici, I have reworded this answer to be more clear in that respect.